# OS X: creating or extracting preview(.jpg,.png) of .eps file

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm using a mac and looking to batch convert a large amount of eps files and create jpg previews of each. I'm looking for preferably a command-line utility, or some type of workflow to easily batch a large number of files.

Thanks for any ideas or input

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like codelogic mentioned, `sips` is a good tool for this. However, it doesn't support EPS natively, so you need to convert to PDF first.

If you're on Tiger or Leopard, something like the following should work:

```
mkdir pdf jpg

cd pdf
echo ../eps/*.eps | xargs -n1 pstopdf
cd ..


sips -s format jpeg *.pdf --out jpg/
```

Assuming your EPS files are in the current directory, this will first convert them all to pdf, storing them in the pdf/ directory, then convert each PDF to a JPEG file in the jpg/ directory.

Comment: thanks soprano,
this is exactly what I was looking for, only problem I'm having is how to write out the jpg to have the same name as the incoming pdf. can't seem to use the wildcard in the --out param

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean. It should make a file with the same basename in the jpg/ directory.

Comment: sips -s format jpeg *.pdf --out jpg/ would not work for me unless I specifically gave --out a filename, like whatever.jpg, otherwise I would get an error saying out_dir_not_found

Comment: Worked great for me, did not need to change anything from the instructions.

Answer (score 5):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) should be exactly what you're looking for.  Once you have it installed, just use the `convert` utility:

```
convert file.eps -resize 25% preview.jpg  # create jpg thumbnail at 25% size
```

Comment: ImageMagick does not appear to support EPS natively. It relies on external programs like `ghostscript`: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#ps

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, you can use [sips](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) to perform image processing tasks, like [thumbnailing](http://www.jonsimpson.co.uk/weblog/2005-06-18/the-depths-of-os-x-sips.html). It should support EPS. If it doesn't, as Adam recommended there is ImageMagick's `convert`.

Answer (score 1):

sips works fine in for me if I drop the trailing '/', i.e. output to jpeg rather than jpeg/

Answer (score 0):

Today you might also exploit GIMP 2.10 or later to make any convenient conversion from jpg to eps, jpg to png and viceversa.